# Calling onKeyDown with Viewpager and Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-webview, onkeydown

How can i make the below code work with a viewpagers that is loading 3 fragments, all are webviews with different URL's. Im simply trying to make it so that when  clicking back on whatever fragment, it calls `web.goBack();`

Here is the code i've used in normal activities, I guess i need recommendations on weather this code should be inside the indivisual fragments or inside the main viewpager. Any suggestions or examples, or code would be greatly appreciated.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int KeyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((KeyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
        web.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(KeyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override this in main Activity and then in on onKeyDown(int KeyCode, KeyEvent event) get your ViewPagers current fragment. In the end you will able to do something like this :

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int KeyCode, KeyEvent event) {

//.. get your fragment

WebView web = fragment.getWeb();

if ((KeyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
    web.goBack();
    return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(KeyCode, event);
}
```

Best wishes.